# Download videos from below link using rtmp

Tags: rtmp

I am a Data Science enthusiast.I am trying to download cs109 harvard videos because it is hard to watch with endless buffering.

Below is the link for first lecture:
https://matterhorn.dce.harvard.edu/engage/player/watch.html?id=e15f221c-5275-4f7f-b486-759a7d483bc8

How to use rtmp to save video from above link?

After doing Inspect Element on webpage it showed below html tag:

```
<source src="https://da4w749qm6awt.cloudfront.net/engage-player/e15f221c-5275-4f7f-b486-759a7d483bc8/275db6f2-3b40-463a-8ec6-a483673e581d/presentation_delivery.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

Comment: Why are you having to use rtmp

Comment: on linux just `wget https://da4w749qm6awt.cloudfront.net/engage-player/e15f221c-5275-4f7f-b486-759a7d483bc8/275db6f2-3b40-463a-8ec6-a483673e581d/presentation_delivery.mp4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why you have to use rtmp

If you just want to save the video, and I'm assuming you have permission and are not breaking any laws, then navigate to https://da4w749qm6awt.cloudfront.net/engage-player/e15f221c-5275-4f7f-b486-759a7d483bc8/275db6f2-3b40-463a-8ec6-a483673e581d/presentation_delivery.mp4 with an HTML5 browser, such as IE, Chrome, Opera or Firefox. You should see the player.

Simply right click on the player and choose Save Video As (you may need to wait a few seconds after the page loads to see this options)